# Converting a list of strings to lowercase breaks down the words into characters

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of sentences like so:
`['Business World - user unable to log in', 'Cannot Login', 'customer getting no signal message on projector', 'Account - colleague is unable to access account', 'Password reset after interruption']` of about 8000 elements.

I want to convert the above list to `lowercase`. I tried using the following line:

```
my_list = [x.lower() for x in my_list]
```

But that gives the error:

> > AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

So I did the following to ensure that all elements are considered as strings:

```
my_list = [x.lower() for x in str(my_list)]
```

This returns the lowers case, but breaks down each word into individual characters?

```
['[',
 "'",
 'b',
 'u',
 's',
 'i',
 'n',
 'e',
 's',
 's',
 ' ',
 'w',
 'o',
 'r',
 'l',
 'd',
 ' ',
 '-',
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need the `str(my_list)`, this serializes it to a string and your loop then iterates over every character of that serialization instead of every element in the list. What you want is `[str(x).lower() for x in my_list]`

Comment: What _do_ you want to happen to the numbers in your input list?

Comment: You don't have a list of sentences. You have a mixed list of strings and integers.

Comment: The fact that you think you have a list of sentences but it turns out some of the elements are `int`s should be giving you pause.  Where did this list of sentences come from and how did `int`s end up in there?

Comment: I tried the code you posted in the question in the python 3.7.2 REPL and it seems to work the way you wanted. I think your input list may contain ints in some places rather than sentences.

Comment: The accepted answer produced the expected result. This was a genuine question of mine and I showed my method and what I had already tried. Dont know why SO is so harsh with such questions and the downvotes. I wont delete this question and will leave it up as it may help someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str(my_list)` serializes your list object to a single string object. Iterating over the string yields every single character in this serialization.

What you probably want is to convert each element into a string (apparently there are also numbers in it outside of your sample) and lowercase that.

```
lower_list = [str(x).lower() for x in my_list]
```

Comment: @StuckInPhDNoMore so the fact that you have integers in a list you expected to have strings is cool? You're coding around a problem you should fix upstream if you use this solution.

Comment: @timgeb The list was an export of a pandas column, which was 8000 long. It was a csv import and it is possible that there may be some integers. Me implementing ``str()`` in my applied method showed that I did not care much for it being mixed. I was just applying it wrong

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that somewhere in your list there are integers, so you need to stringify them.

Try this one:

```py
my_list = [str(x).lower() for x in my_list]
```